# Where can I check who has downvoted to my question/answer?

Tags: discussion, votes

Is there any way to see on SQA site to check who is upvoting or downvoting to my questions/answers?

For example, on Facebook, you can easily find out who has liked/shared your posts.

Comment: I do find it a problem that people are not adding a comment when down voting. _I didn't down vote, here_ ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible.  However, if the downvoting behaviour appears systematic then stackexchange will automatically pick up and correct the fault.

For example, if someone downvotes all your questions during the same day, that rating will be reversed.

I think it is a sensible design decision to hide who votes, as it avoids tit for tat voting